# RabbitMq federated exchange message ordering guarantees

Tags: rabbitmq, message, rabbitmq-exchange

Are there any message ordering guarantees in RabbitMq federated exchanges?

According to
https://www.rabbitmq.com/semantics.html

Section 4.7 of the AMQP 0-9-1 core specification explains the conditions under which ordering is guaranteed: messages published in one channel, passing through one exchange and one queue and one outgoing channel will be received in the same order that they were sent. RabbitMQ offers stronger guarantees since release 2.7.0.

Should I read this as if there's no guarantees between federated exchanges?

Thanks in advance.